# How to convert data type Varchar of date format 'Mar 14 2023 12:00AM' to Date data type in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the data of date column in the following format 'Mar 14 2023 12:00AM' and it is of VARCHAR2 data type. How can I convert it into date datatype in oracle server in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format?

I tried to to_date, but it says

> date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Show us your current `to_date()` attempt. (Have you read the https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html?) Note that the MM/DD etc describes the input data format (your varchar value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the data to **DATE** type by using

```
TO_DATE('Mar 14 2023 12:00AM','Mon dd yyyy hh:miPM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
```

and then apply **`TO_CHAR()`** just to display in the desired format such as

```
TO_CHAR(
        TO_DATE(
                'Mar 14 2023 12:00AM',
                'Mon dd yyyy hh:miPM',
                'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
               ),
        'mm/dd/yyyy'
       ) AS "Date Col"

Date Col
----------
03/14/2023
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TO_DATE` to convert it to a `DATE`:

```sql
TO_DATE(
  'Mar 14 2023 12:00AM',
  'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
)
```

A `DATE` is a binary data-type (it is stored internally as 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds and it always has those components) and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular human-readable format.

If you want the date in a particular format then you need to convert it back to a string:

```sql
TO_CHAR(
  TO_DATE(
    'Mar 14 2023 12:00AM',
    'Mon DD YYYY HH12:MIAM',
    'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
  ),
  'MM/DD/YYYY'
)
```